# f.lux setup.py on xubuntu 16.04 results in error

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, python, f.lux

Took the zip from here and unzipped it: https://github.com/xflux-gui/xflux-gui but when i run `setup.py`

```
$ sudo ./setup.py install
```

Results in the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    rename("xflux64", "xflux")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/)? Maybe you should give a try, I think is best tool of this kind for GNU/Linux, works pretty well. I've tried F.lux on Ubuntu 14.04 but sometimes stop working and I've tried to fix it but always failed.  If you want try Redshift `$ sudo apt-get install redshift`    [Installation for Xfce](http://www.alexforencich.com/wiki/en/linux/redshift_xfce)

Comment: I concur that Redshift works far better on Linux that f.lux.

Comment: Is there a `xflux64` inside the same directory as `setup.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal window ands type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/flux
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then type:

```
sudo apt-get install fluxgui
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That's all. And you got updates for it too.
It seems to me that you didn't got f.lux, but xflux. They are two different projects.

Comment: Is there any easy way to test if flux is working? I've changed the settings to the lowest "temperature" but don't feel like I'm seeing a differance.

Comment: @user1821961: Test flux at different temperatures. If it works on some of them it means it works on all of them. But the effect depends on the environment. Try moving your screen to another environment and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd xflux-gui && cp xflux xflux64
```

The previous answer is the wrong way round as there is no flux64 file to copy.